# Images in CKEditor don't retain size

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

I can't seem to figure out how to retain image sizes in CKEditor.  When an image is sized, and the content is saved, and then edited again, I want the size to stay the same as set originally.

Is there a way to configure this?  If not, I can write JavaScript, so is there an implementation I could approach?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was able to do this with the [Picture](https://drupal.org/project/picture) module:

> The proposed HTML "picture" element (see responsiveimages.org, but has
>   not been accepted for HTML 5) is implemented as a display formatter
>   for image fields. This module is a backport of Drupal 8 picture
>   module. This module will deliver alternate image sources based on
>   device capabilities to prevent wasted bandwidth and optimize display
>   for both screen and print.

Comment: Not sure why there was a problem with this post:  This is the successor of Responsive images and styles and is the preferred module to use, it will allow you an easy upgrade to Drupal 8. But it has no colorbox support (feel free to open an issue) and no support for inline images (feel free to open an issue). The code works a bit different, resp_img overrides image styles while picture is using a display formatter.

Comment: The original version of the answer was really nothing more than a link.  Link-only answers aren't considered good ones, and someone flagged it.  The type of flag carried an downvote from the Community user.  Recommending modules as answers is fine, just give a little context about the module (eg, quote part of the module page), and mention why it would help.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Insert](https://drupal.org/project/insert) module, using this module you can retain the sizes with the help of image cache.

> Insert is a utility that makes inserting images and links to files
>   into text areas or WYSIWYGs much easier. It adds a simple
>   JavaScript-based button to FileField and ImageField widgets. When used
>   with ImageField and ImageCache, images may be inserted into text areas
>   with a specific ImageCache preset.

[image]

- Support for all major WYSIWYG editors, including tinyMCE, **CKeditor**, the WYSIWYG project (the recommended approach), and plain text areas.
- Insert images using ImageCache presets
- Maximum width setting for inserted images (for combined use with the Image Resize Filter module)
- Per-field insert configuration

Comment: I'm not sure this will work for responsive images.  It looks like they are hard coded widths and heights.

Comment: Also, with the image resize filter module, it depends on the WYSIWYG module.  I'm using the standalone CKEditor module.

Answer (score 2):

Look if you have the filter "Limit allowed HTML tags" in your text format, i had the same problem and i fixed it unchecking this field.

Comment: The limit allowed HTML tags filter states that it "...CSS [is] always stripped". Since CKEDITOR resizes images using the `style` attribute, this CSS is stripped by the filter. It's annoying as there does not seem to be a way to use the filter without this over zealous behaviour.